# C# and .NET: TextBox.Text is not always actual?

Tags: .net, winforms

As always, i'm forced to use technologies i'm not familiar with :(. For now it is .NET framework with by C#. It is a simple GUI application with some text fields and the almighty TextBox with the 'Text' property.

It seems that the content of this 'Text' property is not always actual O_O. For example, if i change text and click a button, accessing 'Text' property from button click event handler returns the correct, updated text. BUT if i change text and click an item in the menu bar, the text returned from 'Text' property is... the old one, not changed!

There are no special data bindings or other code. It is all simple forms and visual studio-generated event handlers :(. Maybe some .NET guru can spare a bit of his wisdom and clue me in to why TextBox.Text does not always contain the actual, updated value? Isn't it ::GetWindowText() as a getter implementation?

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: I have never encountered a situation where actual text entered manually into a textbox was not correctly reflected by the Text property.  Could there be some other code manipulation of these controls going on somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "click a top menu"?

Comment: Please share some code showing how you get the text from the text box.  Which language do you use.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was an update code that has changed a text :). Thanks for pointing it up!

Comment: David Hay, can you please copy your comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Text' property is always actual. If it returns a wrong value than it's something in a program logic that changes it.

Answer (score 0):

The button click causes a focus shift from the text box whixh updates the text value, where the menu click will not cause such a focus shift, so the text has not yet been updated in the textbox.

Comment: You don't need to move focus from a `TextBox` control in order for the `Text` property to be updated; you can access the updated text from the `TextChanged` event handler, for instance.